# HTTP POST C# to Cakephp Add controller

Tags: c#, php, cakephp

How do i do http post to a Cakephp controller using c#

I tried the below code using EasyHTTP c# plugin

```
Club club = new Club();
club.passcode="0000";
club.title="Test";
club.id=0;

var http = new HttpClient();
var response=  http.Post(Utils.BASE_URL+"/clubs/add", club, HttpContentTypes.ApplicationXWwwFormUrlEncoded);
```

Unfortunately this is failing to be saved in the add controller. The print_r of **$this->request->data** in the add action is

```
Array
(
    [Id] => 0
    [Title] => Test
    [Passcode] => 0000
)
```

and if i add a club using the web form for the add action it works....and i have noticed that **$this->request->data** is

```
Array
(
    [Club] => Array
        (
            [title] => 12
            [passcode] => 1221
        )

)
```

Can you please assist me with a working method such that c# can post to cakephp controllers action or maybe help me narrow down what is wrong with my request and how to fix it.

Comment: The bit that matters is not the missing Club array key (which is essentially optional) - it's the case of `Id` etc - probably. You should look at the result of your CakePHP save call, and the validation errors if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i solved it,

```
$postdata = array(
    'Club'=>array(
          'title'=>$this->request->data["Title"],
           'passcode'=>$this->request->data["Passcode"]
     )
); 

$this->Club->create();
if ($this->Club->save($postdata)) {
    //Saved
}else{
   //Failed
}
```

Comment: You're better off fixing the problem rather than the symptom ;)